# Is it necessary to use stratified sampling if I am using SMOTE already?

Tags: cross-validation, smote

I have already applied SMOTE to my imbalanced dataset with more than 300K observations. Does it still make sense to use stratified K-fold cross validation rather than simply ordinary K-fold cross validation (seems unlikely each of the K-fold training set would be imbalanced)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to stratify your data after balancing it, since your data is now balanced, so how would you determine the stratification? It would be equal to regular sampling, unless you would use the ratio from before balancing your data, but that is not relevant anymore. Also, the whole point of resampling techniques is to avoid such procedures.

Whether resampling techniques will work for your data is another question. You can't generate new information only from existing information, so there may still be quite a lot of imbalance in your data, even after balancing. This depends a lot on how imbalanced your data was and how much information it contained.